# Representation of signed bounded Radon measures

Tags: measure-theory

This is exercise 5 in section 56 of Halmos's measure theory.

Let X be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\Lambda: C_{c}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded signed Radon measure. That is, $\Lambda$ is linear and there is a $C$ such that $|\Lambda(f)|\leqslant C\|f\|_{\infty}$ for all $f$.

Show that $\Lambda$ is the difference of two *positive* Radon measures ($\Gamma$ is positive iff $\Gamma (f)\geqslant 0$ for all positive $f$.)

I am aware it can be done using (a general version of) the Riesz-Markov theorem and Jordan decompositions for signed measures. But in the Halmos book it is suggested that a direct proof can be made by copying the proof of the existence of the Jordan decomposition, and it is this type of proof that I am looking for.

I solved this exercise a long time ago but now I suspect that I did a mistake in my proof, which I can't recall. I think my strategy was to use Dini's lemma to construct positive and negative functions  ($f\geqslant 0$ is negative iff $\Lambda(g)$ is negative for all $g$ satisfying $0\leqslant g\leqslant f$), but I can't work anything out now.